# Tuckey urlrewritefilter rewrite query string

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to use Tuckey URL rewrite filter to rewrite the query string passed to Solr.

Using the following configuration:

```
<urlrewrite use-query-strings="true">
    <rule>
       <from>^/test1/(.*)command=(.*)clean=true(.*)$</from>
       <to type="redirect">$1command=$2clean=false$3</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

This configuration works if the query string is not read as a query string i.e.

```
http://localhost/test1/command=something&clean=true&somethingelese=new
```

but fails as intended:

```
http://localhost/test1?command=something&clean=true&somethingelese=new
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the question mark in the url.

Here is an example of how I've done it: https://github.com/KevinWorkman/StaticVoidGames/blob/master/StaticVoidGames/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml

But I think all you really want is something like this:

```
<urlrewrite use-query-strings="true">
    <rule>
       <from>^/test1/\?(.*)command=(.*)clean=true(.*)$</from>
       <to type="redirect">$1command=$2clean=false$3</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your examples are really helpful. After looking them over, I realized that I had been including 'use-query-strings="true"' instead of 'use-query-string="true"' so my matching regex was never matching when a query string was used.